# Pythonic way to fetch all elements in a dictionary, falling between two keys?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary object, and I want to extract a subset of the dictionary (i.e. return another dictionary), which contains all elements of the parent dictionary where the key matches a certain criteria.

For example:

```
parent_dict = {1: 'Homer',
               2: 'Bart',
               3: 'Lisa',
               4: 'Marge',
               5: 'Maggie'
               }


def filter_func(somedict, key_criteria_func):
    pass
```

I want to write (in a pythonic way), `filter_func`, so that I can call it like this:

```
filter_func(parent_dict, ">2 and <4")
```

which will return the new dict:

```
{ 3: 'Lisa' }
```

What is the most pythonic way to write `filter_func?`

To keep things simple, I will limit the criteria to simple boolean operations.

**[[Edit]]**

This is the output when I try the following command:

```
>>> {key:val for key,val in parent_dict.iteritems() if 2 < key < 4 }
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    {key:val for key,val in parent_dict.iteritems() if 2 < key < 4 }
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

BTW, I'm running Python 2.6.5

Comment: I added a little explanation on lambdas. Enjoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict((k,v) for k,v in parent_dict.iteritems() if 2 < k < 4)
```

This works for Python 2.6.5.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

Starting from python 2.7, you can use dictionary comprehension. There are like list comprehensions, but applied to a dictionary:

```
>>> parent_dict = {1: 'Homer',
...                2: 'Bart',
...                3: 'Lisa',
...                4: 'Marge',
...                5: 'Maggie'
...                }
>>> {key:val for key,val in parent_dict.iteritems() if 2 < key < 4 }
1: {3: 'Lisa'}
```

You probably don't need to make it a function, but if you do, you can just use a lambda function as a filter:

```
>>> def filter_func(somedict, key_criteria_func):
...     return {k:v for k, v in somedict.iteritems() if  key_criteria_func(k)}
... 
... filter_func(parent_dict, lambda x: 2 < x < 4)
2: {3: 'Lisa'}
```

For Python 2.6.5 and all version before 2.7, replace the dict comprehension with:

```
dict((k,v) for k,v in parent_dict.iteritems() if 2 < k < 4)
```

**Why a lambda function ?**

Lambda function are not magic, it's just a way to easily create fonction on the fly. You can do everything you do with `lambda` witout it, the only difference is that lambdas are expression, and therefor can be used directly between parenthis.

Compare:

```
>>> func = lambda x: 2 < x < 4
>>> func(3)
True
```

With:

```
>>> def func(x):
...    return 2 < x < 4
...
>>> func(3)
True
```

It's exactly the same and produce the same function, except the lambda function won't have a name. But you don't care, on your case you don't need a name, you just need a reference to call it, and the variable `func` contains this reference.

The lambda syntax is weird because:

- You don't need parenthesis for the parameters (you don't even need parameter)
- you don't do `def var(param):` but `var = lambda param:`. Nothing magic, it's just syntax
- you can't make a 2 lines `lambda`: the return result must fit in one instruction.
- you don't use the `return` keyword: the right part of the lambda is returned automatically

Now the nice thing with a lamda, is that since it's an expression, you can use it between parenthese, meaning you can create and pass your fonction à the same time.

Compare:

```
>>> filter_func(parent_dict, lambda x: 2 < x < 4)
```

With:

```
>>> def func(x):
...    return 2 < x < 4
...
>>> filter_func(parent_dict, func)
```

It's exactly the same. The lambda is just shorter.

The hard part here is to understand that you can pass a function as a parameter in Python because everything in Python is an object, including functions.

You can even do this:

```
>>> def func():
...    print "test"
...
>>> ref_to_func = func # assign the function refence to another var
>>> del func # delete this label
>>> ref_to_func() # call the function from this label
test
```

And you can even define a fonction on one line:

```
>>> def func(): print "test"
>>> func() 
test
```

But you can't do this:

```
filter_func(parent_dict, def func(x): 2 < x 4 )
```

Which is where lambdas are useful.

Comment: I knew it would involve lamda functions somehow. I think its time to stop aviding them and read up on them. Any chance you could post a link to an easy introduction to lambad funcs?

Comment: There appears to be a problem with your snippet. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli - @e-satis' version does not work with your Python 2.6.5. You have to use `dict((k,v) …)` instead of `{k:v …}`

Answer (score 1):

for python 2.5.2:

```
dict( (k,v) for k,v in parent_dict.iteritems() if k > 2 and k < 4 )
```